# iOS, sqlite3 parameterized where clause

Tags: uitableview, ios4, sqlite

I'm very new to iOS. I have a UITableview that fill from sqlite3 database. Now I want to make, when a cell click, other database data relevant to that should be displayed in another view. I don't know how to write multiple parameterized where clause for select query. This is the query that I want. Here `nebNO`,`spNO`and `ModelName` values are come in 3 parameters.

`SELECT nebType,nebName,spType,spName FROM All WHERE nebNO='1' AND spNO='1' AND ModelName='MOD144'`

plz hlp me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to create a string that contains your where clause?  If so, then it should look like this (assuming that all three parameters are objects):

```
NSString *whereClause = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT nebType,nebName,spType,spName FROM All WHERE nebNO='%@' AND spNO='%@' AND ModelName='%@'", parameter1, parameter2, parameter3];
char *sql = [whereClause UTF8String];
```

You can also create and compile the select statement once and bind the values to the already compiled statement, but since this is done only once in response to a user clicking a row, you won't gain any performance advantage in doing so.

Comment: I wrote like this `const char *sql ="SELECT NebulizerPartNo,NebulizerImgName,SpraChamberType,SprayChamberPartNo,SprayChamberimage FROM All WHERE SprayChamberNO='%@' AND Models='%@'",self.sprayNo,self.modelName;` but it gives an error `: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token`

Comment: You have to use NSString like I showed.  I added the second line to show how to get a char pointer to use with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is worked.

SELECT nebType,nebName,spType,spName FROM All WHERE nebNO LIKE '1' AND spNO LIKE '1' AND ModelName LIKE 'MOD144'

I hope it helps some one. Please up vote if it helps.